# Word VSTO - Document Open not firing

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-addins

I have created a VSTO addin for Word 2016

On a tab in Word I have a number of buttons, but I only want to show some buttons if the name of the document or another property is a certain value.

But I cannot get it to fire when a document is opened.

Am I missing something?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Dim wordApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_DocumentOpen(Doc As Document) Handles Application.DocumentOpen

        MsgBox("opened")

        If wordApp.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value = "Posting Slip - Client Receipt" Then

            PostClientReceipt.Visible = True

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to get the Word `Application` running instance in the following way from your VSTO Word add-in:

```
 Dim wordApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")
```

Instead, you can use the `Application` property of the add-in class. For example:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```

Second, the `DocumentOpen` event is fired before the add-in is loaded when you double click the file. Since Word 2010, the Word startup behavior is changed, VSTO runtime waits for Word to be ready before firing the `ThisAddIn_Startup` event. In this scenario by that time the `DocumentOpen` and `WindowActivate` events are already fired.

You may find the [DocumentOpen and WindowActivate events do not fire on Word 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3027424c-add3-4935-a822-b517147dbdef/documentopen-and-windowactivate-events-do-not-fire-on-word-2010?forum=vsto) thread helpful.

As a possible workaround at startup you may check for any opened document and call the `DocumentOpen` event handler programmatically.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful, I have made some changes 

I have used the document change event and that is working better, how can I reference the button on the toolbar though?

'''Private Sub Application_DocumentChange() Handles Application.DocumentChange

        If Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value = "Document Name Here" Then

            MyButton.Visible = True

        End If

    End Sub'''

Comment: Sounds like a subject for another post at SO. Please post new questions in new threads so readers could recognize questions and answers easily.